# Directory.exist method issue in Firefox browser

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have  a asp.net page which is checking a UNC path on a listbox item change event using Directory.exist method.

This works fine in Internet explorer.

But when i use firefox and debugging this method returns false even though the directory exists.

What could be the reason for this strange problem.

this is the code

Directory.Exists(@\\SYSMHARSYS\xxxxxxFiles\Region\Error)

when i browse from IE and put a breakpoint here it returns true.But in FF the same code returns false.Its happening only for a UNC.It returns true for a local path(eg Directory.Exists(@C:\test).

Authenticatiion:

authentication mode="Windows"

identity impersonate="true"

Please someone answer this

Thanks

SNA

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem to me. Are you using windows authentication (with identity-impersonate) on the site?

Comment: How exactly are you using `Directory.exist` - client side or server side? Can you post the code?

Comment: this is the code Directory.Exists(@\\SYSMHARSYS\xxxxxxFiles\Region\Error) when i browse from IE and put a breakpoint here it returns true.But in FF the same code returns false.Its happening only for a UNC path.But return true for a local folder.

Authentication:
<authentication mode="Windows"/> <identity impersonate="true"/>

Comment: Is the code in a <script runat='server'> tag, code behind.....

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I bet it's because the credentials in firefox are not being passed correctly, as noted by ck below. Did you ever find a way to make this work in firefox? Works fine in Chrome for me, also.

Answer (score 1):

IdentityImpersonate = true only works by default through IE. In Firefox, it will prompt for a username and password, but if you have saved a previous credential, it might not be able to access the folder anymore.

Comment: FF asked user name and password.So i hav given my windows login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is running on the server-side, it shouldn't make any difference which browser is being used.  Is the directory path parameterised in some way?  If it is, perhaps IE and FF are each returning different values for some reason resulting in an invalid path when FF is used.